# How can I match data from cvs and flat files and create a third file? (one unnamed column in csv file)

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am new in python and this if the first time I ever post something in Stackoverflow.
If anybody could show me the right direction to take I would much appreciate it.
I have two files: one CSV file with over 8000 rows in only one column (column that has no name or isn't defined) and a flat file with 8000 rows as well and each row contains a thousand characters.
Specific numbers appear in both files. I would like to match those specific numbers in both files and if there is a match, I would have to add a number (from 1 to 8000) at a specific position and create a new third file with the final result.
Should I use pandas or simple loops? What info could I give in order to be helped? I apologize if this not clear, it's my first time.

Example of data in flat file (I have to modify only rows that start with 600):

```
1- 01000000000012354568789111
2- 10000012345678978795643211
3- 60000456789
4- 60000457895
```

Example of csv file:

```
1- 324123789456
2- 324123788456
```

There are numbers in the csv file that appear also in the flat file. and when there is a match I have to add a number at a specific row position

Comment: Can you put an example of what would be in the third file?

Comment: 60000456789 000000000000 'the matching numbers' 0000 'the sequencial number (from 0 to 8000)'

Comment: So there if there are these numbers in the csv `11 22 33 44 55` and `11 44 99` in the flat file then the thid file would have `11 44` right?

Comment: first of all, tank you for taking your time. I must be a pain in the ass. to answer your question: if in both files there is a 11 22 33 44 55, the third file will "re-use" that same number 11 22 33 44 55 and in addition to that, at a specific position in that row I have to write a sequencial number starting from 1 let's say. My csv file a data such as 55447026980;000029;200000332378; (in one single unnamed column).

Comment: It's hard to understand exactly what it is, but I think you can brute force it if you only have 8000 rows on each file

Comment: @jipeto -- Please write out the expected output in the original question, rather than a comment.